# Difference between resuming a suspended message or suspended service instance

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

We encounter a bunch of suspended service instances (like 100). Also we notice that there are more than 100 (related) suspended messages (mostly with NACKs).

What is the difference then to resume from a suspended service instance or to resume from a suspended message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service instances process messages.

BizTalk breaks up services into Service Classes, such as Routing Failure, Isolated Adapter, and Messaging. Those services are distinct from the messages, though the messages are associated with a service. When something fails in BizTalk, typically both a message and a service instance show up in the BizTalk Administration Console as being suspended. If you view the details of the service, then you'll see that it contains a tab with the message(s).

In this context, the message is a property of the service instance. The service was trying to do something with the message and failed. Thus is makes sense to resume the action (service instance), which will make use of the data (message). It doesn't make sense to try and do something like resume a NACK (a message); instead, you should resume the service instance. The NACK can help you find out what went wrong, but if it doesn't go away after resolving the problem and resuming the service instance, then it typically can be safely cleared out.